# SSRS - I want to add a filtered expression for a calculation

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

--

I would like to add and expression that calculates a value based on a certain value. I have a dataset with the name  DSSPend that has to columns one is the Area and the other spend. Now I would like to calculate the spend based on certain area values.
I tried something like this but does not seem to work

```
=Iif((Fields!Area.Value, "DSSSpend") IN ('New York','Miami','Texas') = SUM(Fields!Spend.Value, "DSSSpend"), 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=sum(iif((Fields!Area.Value = "New York" or Fields!Area.Value = "Miami" or Fields!Area.Value = "Texas"), 
CDec(Fields!Spend.Value), CDec(0)))
```

There is no IN operator in SSRS expressions. You can achieve the same goal by using OR.

Also, your SUM aggregation needs to go outside the IIF.  Your expression would evaluate the first record only rather than going through each record in the dataset and then aggregating. The expression I have written above goes through the entire dataset, summing either the value in the Spend field or 0, depending on the value of Area.

Update: If you were getting an error before, it was probably because it wasn't seeing your amounts as numbers. By converting them explicitly, you should get around this issue.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply, but I get an error when I run this query as suggested. I have made certain that my Area values are exactly as specified and spelled correctly.

Comment: What is the error? This is the pattern you will need to get the correct answer, so you'll need to post more info for me to be able to tell what's wrong.

Comment: @user1546143 The issue is probably due to data type.  I added CDec() to my expression above and it works fine with my test data. If you need integer instead of decimal change it to CInt.